# Stored Procedure not visible with RO access but visible with RW access in DB

Tags: java, sql, oracle

When I tried to see my StoredProcedure say `MYSP` with RO access using following query:

`select * from all_objects where object_name ='MYSP';`
It is not showing there

But running the same query with RW access,it is there.How?

Also if there is this difference, will JDBC call be impacted in this case?

Comment: encorporated the comments. it is a Stored procedure

Comment: (Assuming RO means read only and RW means read/write): The visibility of a procedure has nothing to do with read or write privileges (which are granted on tables and views) but with the `execute` privilege. So the question is: does that "RO" user have the `execute` privilege for that stored procedure?

Comment: No. RO doesn't have execute privilege .

Comment: Then how do you expect that user to have access to that procedure?

Comment: but then there are other SPs as well which I can see in RO and don't have `execute` priviledge and have entries in `all_objects` table. What may be the issue?

Comment: The 'all_objects' view will only show those objects that you have privileges to see. If you can see procedures/packages in there then you WILL have permission to see them. Maybe there is a role that those objects have been granted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use DBA_OBJECTS, which describes all objects in the database.  ALL_OBJECTS describes all objects accessible to the current user.

If DBA_OBJECTS is not available to a user or group, you can use SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE, which provides SELECT privilege on objects in the data dictionary.  For more, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authorization.htm).

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, we regularly use a Read Only account for our reporting services. In many cases, we have stored procedures instead of sql code in the reports. In those cases, you have to grant Exec to the stored procedure for the account. It is a great way to add a level of security. As for why the user couldn't see the stored procedure, that has to do with the schema the user has access to. Even if a read only account saw the stored procedure, it could not run it until the permission to exec has been given. Though a SQL Server user, my understanding of all_objects is that is a list of available objects to the user, which would mean that the RO account has not been given permission to execute the stored procedure.